# timestamp value info several between sql

Tags: php, sql, between

I wonder is it possible to use the `$get` value in several places in a query?

The `$value` is originally a timestamp that is used like this:

```
 ho.time BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I want to add the value to another column, but is this possible?

```
ho.send BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I tried:

1. `ho.time,ho.send BETWEEN ? AND ?`
2. `(ho.time,ho.send) BETWEEN ? AND ?`
3. `ho.time BETWEEN ? AND ?`

   `ho.send BETWEEN ? AND ?`

But don't get it to work with more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong

Try this.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x BETWEEN 20 AND 80) AND (y BETWEEN 20 AND 120) AND (z BETWEEN 10 AND 40) LIMIT 0 , 30`

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268369/multiple-mysql-where-between-clauses)