# I wanna select some row between 1 and 3 or between 7 and 10 what's the exact query for this in mysql and laravel too?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
SELECT * from jobs where created_at BETWEEN IN('1' and '4', '7' and '10');
```

this is my sql which i tried but it gives error.thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `WHERE created_at BETWEEN 1 AND 4 OR created_at  7 AND 10` should do that.

Comment: there is similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268369/multiple-mysql-where-between-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate out your BETWEEN statements:

```
SELECT * from jobs where created_at BETWEEN 1 and 4 OR created_at BETWEEN 7 AND 10;
```

For Laravel's Query Builder:

```
DB::table('jobs')->whereBetween('created_at', [1,4])
    ->orWhereBetween('created_at', [7,10])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `BETWEEN ... AND ...` queries with an `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE created_at BETWEEN 1 AND 4
   OR created_at BETWEEN 7 AND 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can use `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween()` methods:

```
Job::whereBetween('created_at', [1, 4])->orWhereBetween('created_at', [7, 10])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN 1 and 4 or created_at  BETWEEN 7 and 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by [1, 3, 7, 10] the months, use this:

**I guess your model is Job**

```
Job::where(function($q){
    $q->whereMonth('created_at', '>=', 1)
      ->whereMonth('created_at', '<=', 3);
})->orWhere(function($q){
    $q->whereMonth('created_at', '>=', 7)
      ->whereMonth('created_at', '<=', 10);
})->get();
```

**Note1:** if mean by numbers the days not months, use `whereDay` instead of `whereMonth`
**Note2:** created_at is a timestamp as default